# Quadrilaterals and objects with higher than four vertices

Tags: texturing

I know textures cannot work on triangles and I know they work on quads so can they work on faces with higher than 4 vertices

Comment: Textures work on triangles fine.  They can work on faces with more than four verts (ngons) but the mapping can be hit or miss-- mapping on triangles or quads is preferable.

Comment: Thank you, I wish I could give you a cheesecake right now for helping me.